# Spring download excel using HttpServlet

Tags: excel, spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi

i want to downlaod a created excel file. I'm using POI. This ist my code :

```
 response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    ... // add some sheets


    workbook.write(out);
```

This is my RestService

```
@Autowired
Excel excel;

@RequestMapping(path = "/excel/{testId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity createFile(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable Integer testId) {


    try {
        excel.createFile(response, testId);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);


}
```

This is the result: 
[image]

Storing the file local works.

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to provide more code than that. How do you create the workbook? What is the complete method of your spring controller or servlet?

Comment: Hey i edited my answer hope it will help

Comment: Where you able to resolve this issue? I am running into same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need set the proper values of HttpResponse object

Example

**For .Xls file**

response.setHeader("Content-Type", application/vnd.ms-excel);

response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

**For Excel2007 and above .xlsx files**

response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Admin_SkillsExcelBuilder extends AbstractXlsView{
    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
            Workbook workbook,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        // change the file name
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Skills.xls\"");

         // get data model which is passed by the Spring container
        List<SkillsVO> skillsList = (List<SkillsVO>) model.get("skillsList");

        // create a new Excel sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Skills");
        sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(30);

        // create header row
        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("SNO");
        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("SkillName");
        header.createCell(2).setCellValue("SkillType");


        // Create data cells
        int rowCount = 1;
        int count=1;
        for (SkillsVO skillsList1 : skillsList){

            Row courseRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            courseRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(count);
            courseRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(skillsList1.getSkill());
            courseRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(skillsList1.getSkillType());
            count=count+1;
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadSkillsAsExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView downloadSkillsExcel(HttpSession session, ModelMap model) {
        logger.info("Entered in to downloadSkillsExcel( ) method in Controller");
        try{

        List<SkillsVO> skillsList = keywordsService.getAllSkills("default");
        model.addAttribute("skillsList", skillsList);
        return new ModelAndView("SkillsExcelView");
    }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(ExceptionUtil.getExceptionMessage(e));
        return new ModelAndView("admin_pages/404");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to download the excel file using Spring MVC

**1. Create AS-IS POJO class (or Domain class)**

```
public class Person{

private String name;

private int age;

//Getters and Setters
}
```

**2. Create a Service Class and Extend the AbstractExcelView Class**

```
 public class MyExcelServiceClass extends AbstractExcelView{

      @Override
      protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, HSSFWorkbook workbook,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

           //Now you have Excel WorkBook Object available for processing Excel file using POI API

      }
```

}

Comment: Hi as i mentioned storing the file local works. There must be a mistake in the response. 
1thingtodo